# Angular wrapping angular material tabs component with in custom components

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, frontend, ng-content

What I am trying to achieve here is I wanna wrap the angular material tabs component with in my shared components.

So, here is the component that I'm trying to wrap:

**PS**: I can display component in each tab:

```
<mat-tab-group>
  <mat-tab label="First"> Content 1 </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Second"> Content 2 </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Third"> Content 3 </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

So, I wanna use wrapper for it to use it like:

```
<app-wrapper>
  <app-item>
    <app-item-header title="first"></app-item-header>
    <app-item-content>
      <app-needs-to-be-displayed></app-needs-to-be-displayed>
    </app-item-content>
  </app-item>
</app-wrapper>
```

**app-wrapper.html**

```
<mat-tab-group>
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</mat-tab-group>
```

> no changes in the TS class

**app-item.html**

```
<mat-tab>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
</mat-tab>
```

> no changes in the TS class

**app-item-header.html**

```
<ng-template mat-tab-label>
  {{title}}
</ng-template>
```

**app-item-header.ts class**

```
@Input() title:string = ''
```

**app-item-content.html**

```
<div>
   <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

> no changes in the TS class and this can hold an actual component

This gives no error in the console but nothing appears on the page too.

> **and here is working stackblitz version**
>
> **https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wrapping-component-with-ng-content**

> **PS : Please advice guys if this is the best solution to achieve this
> or there is another solution ?**

Comment: The hierarchy of the stackblitz is more complex that the question. It also using [content projection](https://angular.io/guide/content-projection) where the same selection .app-item seems to conflict in the hierarchy.

Comment: The main idea is i need to wrap ui component which in the example provided by angular material into local components the wrapper in  acomponent and the content in a componenet and so on

Answer (score 6):

You don't see anything because the `mat-tab` components need to be direct children of the `mat-tab-group` component else it is not aware that any tabs exist. For this reason you need to approach things differently. You need to get the content from your custom components and then render everything inside the wrapper component. I think the simplest way is to get the content as templates and it is also very close to what you created. I will start with the lowest components and move up.

The `app-item-content` component can be as you created it. The `app-item-header` needs to be changed. Like for the tabs also the `mat-tab-label` directive needs to be applied directly inside the `mat-tab-group`. That is why I removed it from the template.

```
<ng-template>
  {{title}}
</ng-template>
```

The main change is that I expose the `ng-template` inside the component also as a property in the code using the [ViewChild](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild) decorator. This enables the access of the template also from the outside the component.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-item-header',
  templateUrl: './item-header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./item-header.component.css']
})
export class ItemHeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild(TemplateRef) public headerTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;
  @Input() title:string = ''
}
```

After you can move to the `app-item` component. Here there is also just a small change in the template. Using the same approach as in the header component you can get the template for the item content.

```
<ng-template>
    <ng-content select="app-item-content"t></ng-content>
<ng-template>
```

In code you can then again use the [ViewChild](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild) decorator to get the content template as before. The header is a child component of the item to get it you need to use a different but similar [ContentChild](https://angular.io/api/core/ContentChild) decorator to get access to the header component which provides the header template.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-item',
  templateUrl: './item.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./item.component.css']
})
export class ItemComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild(TemplateRef) public contentTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;
  @ContentChild(ItemHeaderComponent) public itemHeader: ItemHeaderComponent;
}
```

At this point you have access to everything you need to render the contents inside the `mat-tab` components. In the template you need to render the `mat-tab-group` and a `mat-tab` corresponding to each `app-item` component and the contents from the templates that were exposed before.

```
<mat-tab-group>
  <mat-tab *ngFor="let item of appItems">
    <ng-template mat-tab-label>
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="item.itemHeader.headerTemplate"></ng-container>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="item.contentTemplate"></ng-container>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

As you can see it is quite straight forward you create a tab for each item and render inside the contents from the item. A bit of a tricky thing is the header you need to render the template inside another `ng-template` to be able to add the `mat-tab-label` directive that it is recognized as header content.
To get all the `app-item` components inside the wrapper component you use the [ContentChildren](https://angular.io/api/core/ContentChildren) decorator which gives a list of components inside the content. Like in previous examples we just add a property in code the rest is handled by Angular.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-wrapper',
  templateUrl: './wrapper.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./wrapper.component.css']
})
export class WrapperComponent implements OnInit {
  @ContentChildren(ItemComponent) public appItems: QueryList<ItemComponent>;
}
```

I have created also a [fork of you StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wrapping-component-with-ng-content-1lf4ld?file=src%2Fapp%2Fwrapper%2Fwrapper.component.ts) where you can see it working.

Comment: Any idea how to solve that ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError that can be observed in the StackBlitz?

Comment: You need to delay setting the binding property for the items, so it goes into the next Angular binding cycle. This error happens if you change a property during a binding cycle after the [ngDoCheck lifecycle event](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#lifecycle-event-sequence). The content always comes after that is why this error happens. I have created a [fork of the StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wrapping-component-with-ng-content-1lf4ld?file=src%2Fapp%2Fwrapper%2Fwrapper.component.ts) with one option how to solve this issue by setting another property with a delay.

Comment: @iiceman hello u can start injecting the change detector ref and then in the after view init lifecycle hook u can rerun the detector 
by 
constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
  }